# Error installing eggs with packages for different python version with virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip, mysql-python

I'm not able to install packages with a virtualenv set to a different python version. Here's my $:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-dev build-essential
$ sudo easy_install -U pip
$ sudo virtualenv  --no-site-packages --distribute --python=/usr/bin/python2.6 pootle
$ cd pootle
$ sudo pip install mysql-python
```

Among others, here the error:

```
 pymemcompat.h:10:20: fatal error: Python.h: File o directory non esistente
```

No problems, actually, using the default version of python installed on my system (2.7)ubuntu

Comment: It seems that i only have python-dev for default python version (2.7), while i miss the 2.6 package. How to install them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$ sudo apt-get install python2.6-dev`

Comment: holy crap...i definitively feel myself like homer simpson now! tnx for the answer for the (dummy) question!